# Optimizing Entity Framework query

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I want to get data from a database using `3` tables: questions, answers and authentication_detail. The third tables logs when a certain answer to a certain question is given. I need to compute the number of answer events for all the answers of all the questions in a given time frame to display a statistics chart. I used the following query, but the performance is quite bad. I think I am doing something wrong, but I don't know exactly how else I can proceed.

```
  var qData = questions.Select( qs => qs.Select(q=>new SurveyData            
        {                 
            id=q.id,
            name = q.name,
            answers =q.answers.Where(a=>a.is_archived==false).Select(a=>new AnswerDTO
            {
               id=a.id,
               name=a.name,
               count= a.authentication_detail
               .Where(ad=> ad.authentication.@event.insert_date.HasValue
               && ad.authentication.@event.insert_date.Value >= today 
               && ad.authentication.@event.insert_date.Value.Hour == curHour).Count()
            }).OrderByDescending(el=>el.count).ToList()
        })).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
```

I am using `Entity Framework 6.4.0`.

Comment: For performance help, you need to provide us with the query plan, along with table and index definitions

Comment: What is `questions`? If it's not the `DbSet` from the context then you probably have a n+1 problem. Check the executed query / queries.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so my main problem was I was using nested queries. Someone suggested I fetch all the required data from the db first and perform the operations on that data and it worked. Went down from 15s+ to arround 1-2s.